# Error between linking of firebase and expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

I am using the guide from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql4J6SpLXZA for this part but the creator of the video is using firebase version 8 and I am using firebase version 9 so I am currently facing this issue.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword')
```

I have the following (firebase.js):

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ****,
  authDomain: ****,
  projectId: ****,
  storageBucket: ****,
  messagingSenderId: ****,
  appId: ****
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth()
```

Updated version of firebase.js:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ****,
  authDomain: ****,
  projectId: ****,
  storageBucket: ****,
  messagingSenderId: ****,
  appId: ****
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth()
```

I am also using Firebase "^9.9.4". So the above code actually do not work as it will present me with the error of

```
Unable to resolve "idb" from "node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js"
```

To bypass this, I got this solution from online. By creating metro.config.js in the root folder and typing the following:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

But then now I have the error when I tried to register new user on my application

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword')
```

Under my loginscreen.js, I have the following code that deals with the signups:

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const handleSignUp = () =>{
        auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(userCredentials =>{
            const user = userCredentials.user;
            console.log(user.email);
        })
        .catch(error += alert(error.message))
    }
```

Updated version of loginScreen.js

```
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        console.log(user);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using new [Firebase Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) that uses a functional syntax and not namespaced like the previous version. So `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is a top level function here as shown below:

```
import { auth } from "../path/to/firebase.js"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const handleSignUp = async () => {
  const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  console.log(user);
}
```

Also make sure you export the auth instance:

```
export const auth = getAuth()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Thank you very much as this solves the issue. But pardon me as I just started doing this not long ago. I have another issue now. I have updated the codes and edit the new error in the post.

Comment: @CalvinLin it seems your email might be undefined.